# Formatos en un DateField trabajando con un serializer de Rest Framework

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo un problema con una fecha (FechaBaja) porque en este caso es un campo que puede estar en blanco.

En el frontend uso un datepicker para ese campo de fecha, el formato del datepicker esta especificado a `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',`
Pero el formato en que el serializer me devuelve los datos es yyyy-mm-dd

Hasta ahora venía usando las fechas en este formato yyyy-mm-dd y no se me había dado este caso.

Para cambiar esto he especificado en el serializer como debe ser el formato de las fechas.

El problema está en que no puedo vaciar el campo, es decir que si pongo 01/01/2018 y luego quiero borrar esta fecha desde el input, me dice que el campo vacio no cumple el formato.

Incluyo parte del modelo y del serializer

Modelo:

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
    FechaContrato = models.DateField(null = True, blank = False)
    FechaRenovacion = models.DateField(null = True, blank = False)
    Renovado = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = True)
    Baja = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = True)
    FechaBaja = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Serializer:

```
class ContratoEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    FechaContrato = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', 'iso-8601'])
    FechaRenovacion = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', 'iso-8601'])
    FechaBaja = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y','iso-8601'])

    class Meta:
        model = Contrato
```

Si comento la linea FechaBaja del serializer, y quito el datepicker de ese input, funciona correctamente, es decir, me permite vaciar el campo cuando sea necesario. Eso si, al especificar una fecha debo hacerlo con el formato por defecto de fecha en el que esta trabajando rest framework  YYYY[-MM[-DD]]

¿Cual es la mejor manera de enfocar esto?

¡Gracias por ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esta es la mejor manera, pero de momento he planteado lo siguiente en el serializer:

```
class ContratoEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, instance):
        a = super().to_internal_value(instance)
        if str(a['FechaBaja']) == '1900-01-01':
            a['FechaBaja'] = None
        return a

    FechaContrato = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', 'iso-8601'])
    FechaRenovacion = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', 'iso-8601'])
    FechaBaja = serializers.DateField(format="%d/%m/%Y", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', 'iso-8601',''])
```

La cuestión es que construido el serializer así, si dejo el input en blanco, internamente al método `to_internal_value` le llega FechaBaja con el valor '1900-01-01', y así lo identifico para borra el valor de FechaBaja.

No se bien la razón por la que asigna '1900-01-01', pero de momento es funcional.